# rendering returned html code to be shown as a view

Tags: node.js, express, mustache, template-engine

so i'm saving the current Date in a cookie and I try to show the value of this cookie in a html web page using a template engine. The problem is when i send my new template which contains the Date, i get a HTML text instead of a view.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let template = fs.readFileSync(indexFile, 'utf8');
    var dataToShow = {"cookie_data": 'Letzte Besuch: ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()};
    template = mustache.render(template, dataToShow);
    res.send(template);
})
```

And in my HTML page i have the following :

```
<p>{{cookie_data}}</p>
```

I expect to have a view instead of html-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using

```
<p>{{{cookie_data}}}</p>
```

Please refer this doc: http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping

Please use

```
res.render('page', 'params')
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: actually it does already work, but my problem is ```res.send(template)``` returns a html-code and instead of having a view I end up having html-code as plain text

Comment: That the expected behavior of res.send(). It send the data what ever and just renders it. I think you are looking for something like res.render('/route-to-the-page', anyData)